# Large Number to Short Java Android

Tags: java, android

- I have one application of quotes which have likes and sharing
  function.
- I am displaying likes and share number in it with normal way like
  100,1050 etc. Now **I want show number like 1.1K....1.2M etc.**
- I have searched lot for it but not finding any proper way to do it.
  Let me know if someone here can give me any reference or idea for
  same.
- I do not want change number if it's in three digit. **I want convert it
  if there number is 1000-1049 than it will be 1K and if number is like
  1050-1100 than it will show 1.1K and so on.**

  Let me know if You have any idea for do same. Thanks

Comment: Check this out. http://stackoverflow.com/a/30661479/2975371

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please visit https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9769554/how-to-convert-number-into-k-thousands-m-million-and-b-billion-suffix-in-jsp

Answer (score 1):

Had the same task a while ago. Found some nice code snippet, but don´t have the link anymore.

```
public static void main (String[]args) {
    for (long num : new long[] { 999,1000,1049,1050,1100,5432, 19999, 654321, 7000000, 7654321, 80010000, 88888888, 9999999 })
        System.out.println(formatNumber(num));
}  

public static String formatNumber(long count) {
    if (count < 1000) return "" + count;
    int exp = (int) (Math.log(count) / Math.log(1000));
    return String.format("%.1f %c", count / Math.pow(1000, exp),"kMGTPE".charAt(exp-1));
}
```